# ImportError: cannot import name 'Layer' from 'keras.engine'

Tags: python, keras

I am facing a difficulty in solving this error.
I want to pass the Layer object to a class in python,I am facing an import error.
Here is the error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mianafra/Documents/NLP/D2V-BiGRU-CRF/annotate_docs.py", line 3, in <module>
    from wrap import Sequence
  File "/Users/mianafra/Documents/NLP/D2V-BiGRU-CRF/wrap.py", line 6, in <module>
    from models_d2v import BiLSTMCRFD2V_to_dense, save_model, load_model
  File "/Users/mianafra/Documents/NLP/D2V-BiGRU-CRF/models_d2v.py", line 10, in <module>
    from layers import CRF
  File "/Users/mianafra/Documents/NLP/D2V-BiGRU-CRF/layers.py", line 9, in <module>
    from keras.engine import Layer
ImportError: cannot import name 'Layer' from 'keras.engine'
```

Comment: You would have to fix the code, the import from keras.engine is not correct and does not work in latest keras versions.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thanks alot, I jsut updated the import statement from " from keras.engine import Layer" to " from keras.layers import Layer" and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed the correct Keras version required by the project.

If it's [this D2V-BiGRU-CRF](https://github.com/amarnamarpan/D2V-BiGRU-CRF) project, it [seems to be](https://github.com/amarnamarpan/D2V-BiGRU-CRF/blob/45ea7dd7320b6e387f699c44c8157d4ff0000015/Requirements.txt#L4)

> keras==2.2.0

Comment: I tried to downgrade the keras version, but due to M1 I can't downgrade to earlier versions because they aren't compatible with this architecture i guess

Comment: Too bad – then you'll need to fix the project to work with the newer version of Keras and TF.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your tensorflow installation, have you tried to reinstall tensorflow?
maybe try look here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24847.

Try install keras without tf package using:

```
pip3 install keras
```

Comment: I already faced difficulty in Tensorflow Installation, since I am using a M1, so I ended up installing Tensorflow version availble on apple site

Comment: have you tried installing via conda and `pip install tensorflow-macos`? use this guide https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/ you need *arm64 : Apple Silicon* installation

Comment: yeah, I am currently using that version

Comment: There is nothing wrong in tensorflow, you are just speculating.

Comment: have you install keras or you are using keras from tf?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @EyalElbaz I installed keras. I didn't used keras from tf. btw I followed Dr.Snoopy instructions and error was resolved